# Unable to call Angular Controller on a new page in Phonegap Framework7

Tags: angularjs, cordova, html-framework-7, angular-controller

The Angular controllers work fine in the index page, but when I call them from a linked page, they don't work. What do I need to do with the controllers to be able to work with pages too?

My index page has the app defined.

```
<html ng-app="MyApp">
```

I've linked the external page like:

```
Click <a href="about.html">here</a> to go to About
```

On About Page I have:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controller/MyAboutPageController.js"></script>
<div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="left">
            <a href="#" class="back link">
                <i class="icon icon-back"></i>
                <span>Back</span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="center sliding">About</div>
        <div class="right">
            <a href="#" class="link icon-only open-panel"><i class="icon icon-bars"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="pages">
    <div data-page="about" class="page">
        <div class="page-content">
            <div class="content-block" ng-controller="MyAboutPageController">
                <p>Here is About page!</p>
                {{name}}
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried with `MyApp.angular.controller(` and `MyApp.controller(`, both dont work. Also I included `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/controller/MyAboutPageController.js"></script>` in index and About page and doesnt help.

`MyAboutPageController`:

```
 MyApp.angular.controller("MyAboutPageController", function($scope){
    $scope.name = "John Wick Test";
    console.log("MyAboutPageController loaded fine!!");
});
```

The About page loads fine but the controller dont. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Angular was designed to help you creating SPA (Single Page Applications), that means that you do not have to navigate between pages (no postbacks, no new pages).

I recommend you to use ng-view and $routeProvider, so something like this:

```
<head>    
...
<script src="scripts/app/index.js"></script>
</head>
```

then in your body:

```
<body ng-app="YourApp">
...
Click <a href="#!about">here</a> to go to About
<div ng-view></div>
```

in your index.js:

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
    .when('about', {
        templateUrl: 'Views/about.html',
        controller: 'AboutController'
    })
...
app.controller("AboutController", function($scope){
$scope.name = "John Wick Test";
console.log("MyAboutPageController loaded fine!!");
});
```